# ¿Cómo recuperar archivos eliminados localmente tras clonar con git pull?

Tags: git

¿Cómo puedo recuperar archivos que 'accidentalmente' haya borrado en mi PC local?

Me explico:

1. Hacemos un `git clone` de un repo remoto. Tras esto, tenemos una copia de este repositorio en nuestro local.
2. Accidentalmente borramos varios archivos de este repositorio local. De esta manera el repositorio remoto seguirá teniendo toda la información.
3. Intentamos hacer un pull (`git pull origin master`) para volver a tener en nuestro repositorio local todo lo que hay en el remoto.
4. El comando `git pull` no da ningún error, pero en nuestro repositorio local siguen faltando aquellos archivos que borramos por accidente.

¿Cómo podemos recuperar esos archivos borrados?

Sé que una opción sería volver a realizar un `git clone` y santas pascuas, pero sé que debe haber una manera menos engorrosa de conseguirlo.

Comment: Soy nuevo en este blog y quizá no entiendo como funciona todavía,. pero cual es la razón de editar mi pregunta? Que problema hay en añadir un "gracias"? Lo pregunto para evitarlo en futuras preguntas, sin ningún tipo de ironía.

Comment: Adso4: se tiende a eliminar todo aquello que no sea la pregunta en sí. Esto se hace porque el espacio es precioso y se busca un estilo directo. Puedes leer al respecto en [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1624/83). La idea es devolver el favor respondiendo preguntas de otros programadores. ¡Bienvenido!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te has bajado un repositorio y estás trabajando localmente. Aquí es donde eliminas algún fichero y de repente quieres recuperarlo.

En este punto es bueno escribir:

```
git status
```

Dodne verás cosas del tipo:

```
$ git status
On branch tu-rama
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/release-0.3.0' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)


    modified:   un_fichero_modificado
    deleted:    un_fichero_eliminado
    deleted:    otro_fichero_eliminado

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    un_fichero_nuevo
```

La parte importante es la que dice:

> use `git checkout -- <file>...` to discard changes in working directory.

Es decir:

> usa `git checkout -- <file>...` para descartar los cambios realizados en el directorio donde estás trabajando.

Por tanto, en nuestro ejemplo simplemente deberías hacer:

```
git checkout un_fichero_eliminado
```

Answer (score 1):

Con git pull no se puede recuperar un fichero que hayas borrado. Así que te queda esta opción (sin contar el

Si mal no recuerdo era el siguiente comando:

```
git checkout HEAD^ ruta_fichero
```

Comment: Hola @AntonioM . por que el pull no traería el archivo eliminado? no se supone que el pull te trae todo lo que está en el repo local? soy nuevo en git y aún no entiendo ciertas cosas. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

@JulianProg un git pull no trae los archivos borrados.

Si por ejemplo hubieses clonado un repositorio (`git clone git@gitlab.com:usuario/repo.git`) con 4 archivos:

```
$ cd repo
$ ls -lA

README.md
d.sh
b.jpg
c.json
```

y llegaras a borrar por error 2 de ellos:

```
$ rm -rf d.sh c.json
```

Y después hicieras un `git pull`, git te diría *Already up to date.*
O ejecutaras `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    d.sh
        deleted:    c.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

La forma de recuperar estos archivos es con la opción `restore`:

```
$ git restore d.sh c.json
```

o, como bien dijo @fedorqui 'SO deja de dañar', hacer un `checkout` de ellos:

```
$ git checkout d.sh c.json
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso funcionó con el siguiente comando:

```
git restore -- un_fichero_eliminado
```

Con este comando automáticamente se restauró el archivo.